# Keyframe or parent separate meshes in same object?

Tags: objects, parent

I know I can use keyframes and use parent-relations in meshes in **individual** objects. But is it possible to keyframe or use parent relations to separate meshes in **the same object** (maybe when I use vertex groups)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Use vertex groups and armatures.

If an armature can move an attached hand of a human body mesh then it can also move disconnected sub meshes of a Blender Mesh Object.

Parent the mesh to an armature.  Use weight painting if necessary.  Armature need not to be connected. Think of the armature as a collection of controllers and not a mechanism to control an organic mesh model.